# Sorting by keys in underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have one dictionary:

```
{
    abc : {id : 1},
    defg : {id : 2}
}
```

I want to sort dictionary by keys length using underscore.js
Output like:

```
{
    defg : {id : 2},
    abc : {id : 1}
}
```

Prototype work:
http://jsfiddle.net/UCWL2/71/

Comment: It's been only 10 minutes, give OP some time @RishiPrakash ;) I'll give you an upvote, though!

Comment: @kamituel Oh, Ok. I won't be greedy :) :)

Comment: Why do you give one set of data in your question--an object to be sorted--and another set of data in your fiddle--an array to be sorted?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary, which is a plain JS object, can't be reliably sorted, because the order of elements isn't specified by the ECMA Script 5 spec. Of course, you might rely on the browser-specific behaviour, but that isn't guaranteed to be the same accross browsers, their versions etc.

If you need sorted maps, you'd want to use arrays (but then you lose the log(n) access complexity), or some 3rd party library for that (i.e. [dsjslib](https://github.com/monmohan/dsjslib)).

Comment: Just one ques, I didn't get any points for these upvotes, do you have any idea why it happen?

Comment: @RishiPrakash - It seems you've achieved 200 rep points today - that's the limit, congrats! [See doc for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 1):

```
var avatars = [
    {idx: 102, userInfo: {buddy_name: 'Avatar102', is_online: 1}},
    {idx: 100, userInfo: {buddy_name: 'Avatar100', is_online: 1}},
    {idx: 101, userInfo: {buddy_name: 'Avatar101', is_online: 1}}
];

avatars = _(avatars).sortBy(function(avatar) {
    return -avatar.idx;// -ve is put in front of variable to sort in desc i.e reverse direction
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(avatars));
```

Just replace  return avatar.idx;//.userInfo.buddy_name; by  return -avatar.idx;//.userInfo.buddy_name; it reverses the result.

Working jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/0Lb44h96/

Comment: The question was about sorting a dictionary, not about sorting an array.